# Create icon for SageMath on Mac

Tags: sage

I have installed sagemath on my macbook (10.15.7) and I don't want to run sagemath via Terminal. So I was wondering whether I could create an icon so that I can launch it via Launchpad. If that is possible, could you please tell me how to do that? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the new SageMath app for macOS, currently in beta-testing:

- Sage-macOS home: https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS
- releases: https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases